# Is it possible to implicitly create a new firestore collection using java

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to programmatically create a new firestore collection using a variable as the collection reference, but I keep getting an error, is there some specific way to do this, which isnt mentioned in the documentation, or this just cant be done. This is for java in android studio btw.

I tried using a varible as the collection refernce but it doesnt work.

Comment: hi, please improve the question by at least adding the error that you received in a code block.

Comment: Collections are automatically created when you add a document to them, and automatically deleted when you delete the last document from them. There is no separate operation to create/delete a collection. --- If you're struggling to make this work, please edit your question to show the [minimal code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link please, it's quite useful).

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.